# Bluetooth 4.0 (BLE) Java Library

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am attempting to get Java to communicate with a device that only supports Bluetooth 4.0

I've done some testing with BlueCove, but to the best of my knowledge, it does not support Bluetooth 4.0

Are there any libraries available to achieve this? I've searched high and low and came up with no straight forward solutions.

If there are none available, could someone recommend the best way I could make it work? In other questions similar to this one, some people have suggested doing a JNI wrapper for existing C/C++ libraries. If that is the best approach, what would be the best library to wrap?

I'd rather not have to resort to doing that, but if it's the only way I guess I will need to. I've been constrained to using Java and a device that only supports Bluetooth 4.0

**EDIT:** For anyone interested, my solution was to go with using Bluegiga's BGAPI. This limits me to only using their dongle (BLED112) BUT it is a workable solution. I went with [this Java implementation of BGAPI](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/bglib). It has a dependency for an RXTX library, I decided to go with  [this one](https://github.com/NeuronRobotics/nrjavaserial) . Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I think I stated the problem clearly. I am unable to find a way to make Java communicate to a Bluetooth 4.0 device. I've done research on this topic and it appears there is nothing currently available. I checked on stackoverflow and google, and to the best of my knowledge something like this does not yet exist. That's the problem, and research is what I've done so far to try and solve the problem.

Comment: Beside using JNI, the only thing that comes to my mind is to check out Bluez DBus API. Maybe you can use existing java dbus libraries to access Bluez functionality that way.

Comment: I think something to be added was whether your platform (PC? Mac? Android? iOS?) supports BLE inherently or not. The BLED112 is a good solution overall though.

Comment: i was encountering the same as yours @kaimbe....